# Correct way to update an objects state in react (Merged state? Spread operators?)

Tags: reactjs

I've been using React for a bit now, and I've always updated an object's state using the spread operator as I remember reading you should directly change current state.

E.g now I write something like this:

```
const changeState = () => {
  setState(prevState => {...prevState, existingKey: 'new value'})
}
```

But I've just come across a section "State Updates are Merged" in the react docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged).  If I'm understanding it correctly it's essentially saying I can just write this instead:

```
const changeState = () => {
  setState({existingKey: 'new value'})
}
```

and all other keys in the object will remain as is, only the key I have specified will be updated in state.  Am I reading this correctly? I've never seen this on stackoverflow, I always see people saying to use spread operators, is there a reason why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the functional state update and shallow copying is recommended is that is works for all use cases. The [state-updates-are-merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) link you reference actually applies to class-based component's `this.setState` method.

- Enqueueing multiple updates within a single render cycle, loops, etc...

  ```
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  ```

  The net result here is only a single `count + 1` update as each update overwrote the previous one.

  ```
  this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
  this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
  this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
  ```

  The net result here is now `count + 3`.
- Referencing the previous state in callbacks to avoid stale enclosures.

  ```
   componentDidMount() {
     setInterval(() => this.setState({ count:  this.state.count + 1 }), 1000);
   }
  ```

  Here the initial `count` state is closed over in callback scope and will never update.

  ```
   componentDidMount() {
     setInterval(() => this.setState(prevState => { count:  prevState.count + 1 }), 1000);
   }
  ```
- Only the root properties are merged, more deeply nested state being updated also needs to be shallow copied.

  ```
   this.setState(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     property: {
       ...prevState.property,
       nestedProperty: 'new value',
     },
   }));
  ```
- On the off-hand chance you are using the `useState` hook, state updates ***are not*** shallowly merged.

  [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

  > Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does
  > not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
  > behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
  > syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > const [state, setState] = useState({});
  > setState(prevState => {
  >   // Object.assign would also work
  >   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
  > });
  > ```

### A good rule of thumb

If the next state *depends* on the previous state in *any* way, use a functional state update. Otherwise, the regular update is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

For Functional components, the syntax would be:

```js
const changeState = () => {
  setState(prevState => {...prevState, existingKey: 'new value'})
}
```

For Class components, the syntax would be:

```js
const changeState = () => {
  // Notice the use of this
  this.setState({existingKey: 'new value'})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//Use react hooks for the functional component

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//Suppose a user object with name, age, gender properties.

let [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    name: "Somnath Jana",
    age:27
    gender: "Male"
})

useEffect(()=>{
   userData.age = 28
   setUserData({...userData})
},[])
```

Comment: FYI `userData.age = 28` mutates the state object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yeah I thought you weren't meant to do this and that you are meant to create a copy of userData before changing the age property.

Comment: This is just wrong. As @DrewReese stated, this will mutate the state causing subtle bugs